# DB Connection problem "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')" (Identity ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

I am trying to make the connection with the DB hosted on Azure but I have some problem in the code, when I run the application it results in an error in the parameter: connectionString.

**STARTUP.CS**

```
{
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddDbContext<Contexto>
        (
            options => options.UseSqlServer("Data Source=Exemple.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=NameDataDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=UserDB;Password=***********")
        );
        services.AddDbContext<IdentityContexto>
        (
            options => options.UseSqlServer("Data Source=exemple.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=NameUserDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=userdb;Password=***********")
        );
```

**CONTEXTO.CS**

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("NameDB"));
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}
```

When I run the application I have the following error:

```
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')
```

Comment: configuration.GetConnectionString("NameDB")) - here is the problem, I suppose because with this code you say ASP.NET Core look into the appsettings.json and other included json files and find 'NameDB' parameter.

Comment: this configuration.GetConnectionString("NameDB") is null, show your appsettings.json, you should have a section like this "ConnectionStrings": {
    "NameDB": "<your-connection-string>"
  },

Comment: Please mark the answer if that resolved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

configuration.GetConnectionString will NOT get your connections string UNLESS you add them in appSettings like so:

> {   "ConnectionStrings": {
>       "BloggingDatabase": "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFGetStarted.ConsoleApp.NewDb;Trusted_Connection=True;"
>   }, }